# Does total aerodynamic force include skin friction/shear streses contribution?

Tags: aerodynamics

Does total aerodynamic force by definition  include skin friction/shear streses contribution or this only represent overall intergration of static pressure(normal to surface) around wing/airfoil?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Skin shear, due to friction between the airflow and the skin, is one way *how* force is transmitted from the airflow to the solid body.  The pressure distribution is the other main way.  If a definition of total aerodynamic force excluded one of these, it would be incomplete.

One way to think of total aerodynamic force is to just measure it, period.  It is what it is.  Another way is to try to split it up into its parts and put it back together again.  The second way is less accurate, but more useful for theory and modeling.

Comment: The aerodynamic force is the reaction of a body to the force applied to it by a gas stream. The magnitude and direction of that reaction is independent of any phenomena that may take place within that body...